# C# showing textbox in UI, stopping main thread and then resuming

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I am having a little trouble doing something which should be  simple, I am using a simple graphical interface to show data coming from a kinect sensor, and I want to create a transition, that is, I want to show the user a video   and then I want the program to resume its operation. My code goes like this:

```
  private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {



         Random random = new Random();
         int periodo=random.Next(9000,20000); 
         contador.Interval = periodo;

         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(CreateTextBox),null);
         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(StopThread), null);
         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(Advance), null);
         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(ResetTime), null); 
         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(ShowSample), null);
    }
```

This creates a timer with a random time between 9 and 20 seconds. After that I want to do a series of things, which are: 
Showing a message in the UI 
Stopping all activities in the UI
Showing a video in the UI
Resetting a variable
Showing a Video sequence

and the functions used are:

```
   private void CreateTextBox() {

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox { 
        FontSize=40,
        };

        textBox.Text = "Siguiente Actividad";
        canvas2.Children.Add(textBox);           

        // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }

 private void ResetTime() {
        contadorsegundos = 0;

    }

  private void StopThread(){
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
    }

   private void ShowSample() {
        canvas2.Children.Clear();
        MediaElement mediaElement2 = new MediaElement();
        canvas2.Children.Add(mediaElement2);
        string location = "C:\\Users\\PALMA\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Interfaz\\Interfaz\\Videos\\ejercicio1.mp4";
        try
        {
            mediaElement2.Source = new Uri(location);
            mediaElement2.Play();
            //MessageBox.Show(final);
        }
        catch
        {
            //no se atiende la excepción 
            //MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
        }

    }
```

What happens is that the main thread stops for 8 seconds, but the texbox was never shown, even though the function CreateTextBox was called before the function  StopThread, I was expecting that the message would be shown and then the thread would stop.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should never put the UI thread to sleep. That causes all sorts of unpredictable things to happen to the display, and also makes the program unresponsive to the keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the main thread to sleep for 8 seconds, you should use:

```
await Task.Delay(8000);
```

This way you avoid freezing the main thread, which can cause all kinds of unpredictable problems.